# Google Chrome wrong text displaying

Tags: php, google-chrome, utf-8, character-encoding

To make it short, I have a page which has a text "Šmarje" inside.
In Safari and Firefox the text shown is OK. but in Google Chrome I get a "small 8" instead of Š.

I have

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

In my html file.

I have "AddDefaultCharset utf-8" in Apache.
In Google Chrome I set the encoding to Central Europe.
And my file is saved as UTF-8.

I also tried echo the text from encoded UTF-8 MySql database and still..it works fine in Safari and Firefox, but not in Chrome.

For letters Č,č,Ž,ž there is no problem. My Google Chrome has only problem with the letter Š,š.

I tried using htmlentities, but it is not working... If I copy/paste the strange symbol that compares instead of "Š", the copied letter is "Š"..

MOVED HERE: [Google Chrome wrong character - bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28636624/google-chrome-wrong-character-bug?noredirect=1#comment45573099_28636624)

Thx for any help!

Comment: Is the in the html or is it from another source (SQL, csv, textfile read)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Chrome wrong character - bug?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28636624/google-chrome-wrong-character-bug)

Comment: I put it there...I also wrote in the question that I moved the question..

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this and it seems to work fine in Google Chrome. If your grabbing the text from the database have you tried to echo it with htmlentities? like this:

```
<?php echo htmlentities($text); ?>
```

Comment: I tried using htmlentities, but it is not working... If I copy/paste the strange symbol that compares instead of "Š", the copied letter is "Š"..

Comment: maybe display your code here so we can see it and have you tried re-installing chrome, restarting your server or trying out the code in a new script where you can test just this word.

Comment: No I did not reinstall Chrome, but I will try to reinstall it.. I restarted the Server but it didn't help..I will post some code after reinstalling Chrome..

Comment: Ok I found the problem, but don't know how to solve it.. I am using Ubuntu Light font which has Š and works ok in Safari and Firefox, but it is not working in Chrome?
If I disable the font "Ubuntu Light" in CSS the Š compares in Chrome..

Comment: what is the problem you found and have you tried setting google chromes encoding to Unicode (UTF-8)?

Comment: The problem looks like that Chrome doesn't recognise the letter "š" from Ubuntu family font. I have Unicode encoding in Chrome yes...
I took the font from here: http://font.ubuntu.com

Comment: Moved here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28636624/google-chrome-wrong-character-bug?noredirect=1#comment45573099_28636624