# Google Chrome wrong character - bug?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, character-encoding

I did this simple HTML to show you what is bothering me..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<html>

    <style>
        @font-face {
            font-family: "ubuntu-light";
            src: url(Font/ubuntu/Ubuntu-L.ttf) format("truetype");
        }

        h1 {
            font-family: "ubuntu-light";
        }
    </style>

    <body>
        <h1>Ubuntu font test</h1>
        <h1>Š š Ž ž Č č</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can get the font here: http://font.ubuntu.com

So the point is that if I open the Page in Safari or Firefox, the page opens correctly, BUT if I open it in Chrome, the letters Š and š are not displayed correctly.

I tried to put this in my style but is not working:

```
body {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-animation-name: fontfix;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fontfix {
from {opacity: 1;}
to {opacity: 1;}
}
```

I also tried to create a CSS file with this style and then call it at the en of the page with JS but it is not working.

I have "AddDefaultCharset utf-8" in Apache. In Google Chrome I set the encoding to Central Europe and also to UTF-8 but nothing..

Comment: They look fine in my chrome, are you using the latest version?

Comment: Same here. I copied Š š Ž ž Č č and pasted them in font.ubuntu.com and they look fine

Comment: I am using the latest version of Chrome, and also if I go with Chrome on the Ubuntu Font page the letters Š š Č č Ž ž are displayed ok. But with my example html the letters Š and š are not ok. I don't know what am I missing..only Chrome is giving me this strange behaviour..

Comment: Can you post a link to a page where is shows the HTML and displays the character incorrectly?  All of these look correct in my chrome

Comment: I have it locally on my PC..using AMPPS..

Comment: I am also seeing this issue on Chrome 40 on OS X 10.10.2 - My guess is that this issue is OS X only?

Comment: I have OS X 10.9.5..hmm I will try soon with another OS and tell you the results..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed a bug, see its description on launchpad: [Bug #1334363 “Wrong characters appear in some Mac apps ([‘] → [⁸], [’] → [⁹], [–] → [ẃ], [—] → [Ẅ])” : Bugs : Ubuntu Font Family](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-font-family/+bug/1334363)

The reason seems to be a broken Unicode cmap subtable.

You can circumvent this bug if you use a stripped-down version of Ubuntu, for instance a subsetted version served by Google Fonts, for instance with the following style :

`@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:300&subset=latin);`

However, on a computer where the Ubuntu fonts are installed, the characters will still look wrong.

If you want to fix the display on your own computer *and* if you do not need the complete Ubuntu fonts, you can grab the stripped-down versions from Google Fonts. To do this, visit the following Google Fonts stylesheet in Safari, copy the links to the TTF files and download them (in other browsers, the Google Fonts stylesheet will be generated with WOFF fonts that you cannot install on Mac OS X):

http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:300,400,500,700,300italic,400italic,500italic,700italic|Ubuntu+Condensed&subset=latin,latin-ext